# Java arraylist does not keep values that I am passing inside a method

Tags: java, arraylist, parameter-passing, this, instance-variables

I am making an AI game where the cpu stacks N numbered cubes in a table in 3 rows using the Uniform Cost Search algorithm. What I'm trying to do is the `generateMoves()` method, which will return an ArrayList with all the possible moves from a given state.

Cube is a class representing a cube with its own ID (the number of the cube), X axis position and Y axis position.

K is user input

`getCubes()` is a method that returns an `ArrayList<Cube>` which is the current state of the table.

`setCubes()` is a method that takes an `ArrayList<Cube>` and sets that list as the current state.

`isValid()` is a Cube method that checks the copyOfTable list if the given cube is in a valid position.

`isFree()` is a Cube method that checks the copyOfTable list if the given cube is free to be moved.

```java
public class Table{
  private fields

  constructor{}

  public Arraylist<Table> generateMoves(){
    Arraylist<Table> moves = new ArrayList<Table>();
    ArrayList<Cube> currentTable = this.getCubes();
    ArrayList<Cube> copyOfTable = new ArrayList<Cube>(currentTable);

    int X = 1;
    int Y = 1;
    int K = this.getK();

    for(Cube cube : currentTable){
      int backupX = cube.getPosX();
      int backupY = cube.getPosY();

      for(Y = 1; Y <= 3; Y++){
        for(X = 1; X <= 4*K; X++){
          cube.setPosX(X);
          cube.setPosY(Y);
          if(cube.isValid(copyOfTable) && cube.isFree(copyOfTable)){
            this.setCubes(currentTable);

            moves.add(this);

            moves.get(0).printTable();

          }else{
            cube.setPosX(backupX);
            cube.setPosY(backupY);
            continue;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    moves.get(anyIndex).printTable();

    return moves;
  }
}
```

```java
// main is in a different file
main(){
  ArrayList<Table> moves = new ArrayList<Table>();
  Table table = new Table();
  
  moves = table.generateMoves();
}
```

What I want is the `moves.add(this)` to add the current state of the board in the `moves` arraylist, so that I can return all the tables (states) that are possible to be generated by the given table.

The problem is that the first `printTable()` (inside the 3rd for loop), prints every state that can be generated. Not only the first one that I ask it for.

The second `printTable()` (above the return statement), no matter the index, only prints the first state of the table.

What am I missing here?

I tried the above code

Comment: `this` doesn't reference any persistent state but only a reference to the instance of Table you are using.

Comment: To really "save" the state, you would need to design you Table class to be immutable and create new Tables when the state changes.

Comment: @ValerijDobler I created a `new` table, set its state and added it to `moves` arraylist but to no avail. Do I really need to make my whole class final?

Comment: You don’t necessarily need to make the whole class final, but you do need to avoid changing data that you don’t want to change.

Comment: Immutable means, that the class and its fields are not changed not internally or externally. This means, that if your fields contain collections, you have to copy them defensively before returning. Making the class final also helps that it would be extended with a mutable state. Take a look at jdk15 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why (please someone explain that to me), but after i spent a very long time trial-and-erroring, the solution is to make a method that creates a "deep" copy of the ArrayList in question like so:

```java
private ArrayList<Cube> createCopyOfTable(ArrayList<Cube> toCopy){
        ArrayList<Cube> copy = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Cube cube : toCopy){
            Cube _cube = new Cube(cube.getID(), cube.getPosX(), cube.getPosY());
            copy.add(_cube);
        }

        return copy;
    }
```

and the updated part on my `generateMoves()` method:

```java
.
.
.
for(X = 1; X <= 4*K; X++){
    cube.setPosX(X);
    cube.setPosY(Y);

    ArrayList<Cube> copyOfTable = createCopyOfTable(currentTable);

    if(cube.isValid(copyOfTable) && cube.isFree(copyOfTable)){
        Table table = new Table(K);
        table.setCubes(copyOfTable);
                        
        this.moves.add(table);
    }else{
        cube.setPosX(backupX);
        cube.setPosY(backupY);
        continue;
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: ArrayList clone() method is used to create a shallow copy of the list. In the new list, only object references are copied. If we change the object state inside the first ArrayList, then the changed object state will be reflected in the cloned ArrayList as well. If we want to keep the contents separately from source list to the target list, then deep copy is required.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... What am I missing here? ..."*

Your code is correct, you are just misinterpreting the context of the *generateMoves* method.
The returned *ArrayList* will not persist, for each call—there will be a new *ArrayList* per call.

This type of method will need to be placed within a different class.
In which, you can utilize a *ArrayList* class field, to populate a list.

Consider the following.
By passing the *Table* object to *generateMoves*, you can populate the class field *moves*.

```java
class TableUtil {
    static ArrayList<Table> moves = new ArrayList<>();

    static ArrayList<Table> getMoves() {
        return moves;
    }
    
    static void generateMoves(Table table) {
        ArrayList<Cube> currentTable = table.getCubes();
        ArrayList<Cube> copyOfTable = new ArrayList<Cube>(currentTable);

        int X = 1;
        int Y = 1;
        int K = table.getK();

        for(Cube cube : currentTable){
            int backupX = cube.getPosX();
            int backupY = cube.getPosY();

            for(Y = 1; Y <= 3; Y++){
                for(X = 1; X <= 4*K; X++){
                    cube.setPosX(X);
                    cube.setPosY(Y);
                    if(cube.isValid(copyOfTable) && cube.isFree(copyOfTable)){
                        table.setCubes(currentTable);

                        moves.add(table);

                        moves.get(0).printTable();

                    }else{
                        cube.setPosX(backupX);
                        cube.setPosY(backupY);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        moves.get(table.anyIndex).printTable();
    }
}
```

Create your *Table* objects, and then call the *generateMoves* method, for each instance.

For example,

```java
Table tableA = new Table();
Table tableB = new Table();
Table tableC = new Table();

TableUtil.generateMoves(tableA);
TableUtil.generateMoves(tableB);
TableUtil.generateMoves(tableC);

ArrayList<Table> moves = TableUtil.getMoves();
```

Comment: is this considered good practice, or am I in an extreme case where the line is blurred?

Comment: Also, since we have a `static ArrayList moves`, why do we need to create an other normal one inside the `generateMoves` method?

Comment: @SteliosP.98, yes, of course there are many ways to harness the data, although this design is referred to as a _"utility class"_.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helper_class.

Comment: @SteliosP.98, in terms of the _static moves_, you're right, I forgot to remove the local variable.  So, you'll want to be appending the class field, rather.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work. While `moves.add(table)` does add the table to the `moves` arraylist (if I use `moves.get(index).printTable()` right after, it does print all the states), it seems that outside of the 3rd _for_ loop scope the `moves` arraylist get only the first state as its every element. Meaning that if I use `moves.get(index).printTable()` at the end of the method, I only get the first state X amount of times.

Comment: @SteliosP.98, I'm not sure I entirely understand the application you're creating.  I recommend setting a breakpoint on the first _for-loop_ and stepping through each line.  I'm sure you'll locate the inaccuracy.  Additionally, you can override the _toString_ method for both _Table_ and _Cube_, which would allow you to print out the list with _System.out.println(moves)_, or _...println(currentTable)_.